# Toggle nested md-list-item with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im trying to toggle a `menu-item` *(md-list-item with ng-repeat-start)* and each item has a `sub-items` *(md-list-item with ng-repeat-end)*.

I would like that when a user click a particular `menu-item` **ITS ONLY** `sub-items` will appear.

But i can't figure out how to to that with `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`

Here is what i did so far. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/ZLeJLp?editors=1000). You can click the menu but all sub-items in all menu-items got toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `open` flag to the JSON data, so that each list item has its own flag, then on item click you toggle the flag only on the clicked item.

JS:

```
$scope.clickItem = function(item) {
  item.open = !item.open
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-list-item  ng-click="clickItem(item)" style="margin-left: 10px;"ng-repeat-start="item in nestedList">                  
  {{item.id}}
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item ng-show="item.open" style="margin-left: 50px;" ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child in item.children">                  
  {{child.id}}
</md-list-item>
```

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKpZmm